# Swapping sticky modifiers

Tags: keyboard, xkb

You can turn on sticky modifier keys with

```
xkbset sticky
```

but is it possible to get a sticky <kbd>Hyper</kbd> when tapping <kbd>Super</kbd> and vice versa?